# NAudio Asio Unsupported sourceStream format

Tags: c#, audio, naudio, asio

I read everything I can about NAudio but I can't get a solution here.

The project is a VS C# Windows form.

Testing with NAudio and ASIO4All is successful with mono and stereo wav files but trying to play a 8 ch. (44k/16bits) wav file always give an "Unsupported sourceStream format" error. Is it a NAudio limitation? Any idea?

The 8 ch. wav file tested plays perfectly in Asio capable players...

```
void nAudioPlay()
    {
        wave = new WaveFileReader("piano2.wav");
        output = new AsioOut("ASIO4ALL v2");
        output.Init(new WaveChannel32(wave));
        output.Play();
    }
```

Comment: does your soundcard have 8 outputs? you can't open ASIO with more outputs than your device actually has

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tryed to use

```
output.Init(wave);
```